# We should call it "Uluru" but let people find it when they search for "Ayers Rock"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

Not trying to pick on anyone but we have another backwards pair of tag synonyms.

The big red rock in the Centre of Australia has been officially and correctly called "Uluru" for some time now.

But some people still think of it by its old name, "Ayers Rock". That's fine - we have tag synonyms for that.

But we should really have the official and culturally aware name as the main tag, and the deprecated name as the synonym. I'm assuming it's reversed just through a bit of wine inspired syxlesia or something.

- [uluru](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uluru) (main tag that shows up everywhere)

  - [ayers-rock](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayers-rock) (a synonym of the former that redirects to it when you try to use it)

Please reverse which tag is the main one and which is the synonym (-:

Comment: Sigh, sorry, my fault.  :( I swear I read what you wrote and that you'd asked for Ayer's rock as the master, and even remember thinking 'he's an Aussie, he'll know what's best', and taking care to do it that way.  Even went back and checked the chat logs.  Clearly I didn't get enough sleep last night.  Which is ironic, as I'm writing this at 1.20am.  Night ;)

Comment: I must still be typing with a strong Aussie accent. You're lucky I don't have a Georgian accent yet (-: Then again I was thinking maybe both you and Ankur swapped them causing them to get swapped back... but that wouldn't explain why the "uluru" tag is utterly vanished `\-:`

Comment: What version do Japanese tourists use? On the one hand, they sometimes use archaic English, but on the other, Uluru sounds custom-designed for katakana!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: According to Wikipedia, ウルル (ururu) is the newer term, and エアーズロック (eāzurokku) is the older term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your wish is my command, my liege. Done.

Comment: Thanks honeybunch. Actually it's not showing up fixed yet, but that could be one of those icky lag effects due to the distributed database. I'll accept this when I actually *can* verify it (-:

Comment: Nope it's been over an hour and there now seems to be only an [tag:ayers-rock] tag and no [tag:uluru] tag at all - not even a synonym! could you have another look at it?

Comment: it does sometimes take several hours to sort out, from what I've seen in the past.

Comment: It's now 11 hours and still no sign of any [tag:uluru] as either main tag or mere synonym...

Comment: That's weird...in the tag list, it definitely shows up as mapped... :s

Comment: I can see it now atleast..